# Is it possible to put the grouping field on top of the table in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

Is it possible to do this kind of layout in SSRS?

```
2012/11/01
-----------------------------
| Order # | Product   | Qty |
-----------------------------
|         | Mouse     | 3   |
|    1    | Keyboard  | 2   |
|         | CPU       | 5   |
-----------------------------
|         | Mouse     | 1   |
|    2    | Keyboard  | 7   |
|         | Lan Cable | 7   |
-----------------------------

2012/11/02
-----------------------------
| Order # | Product   | Qty |
-----------------------------
|         | Mouse     | 2   |
|         | Keyboard  | 8   |
|    3    | Memory    | 4   |
|         | CPU       | 2   |
|         | Battery   | 1   |
-----------------------------
```

I tried finding a property that could do that, tried dragging the field on top too but to no avail :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this, it's easiest if you nest two tablixes (a table inside a list). Make a list that groups on the date field. Inside the list place the table that groups rows on the order id. This would look like this:

```
                                       ----
2012/11/01                                 |
-----------------------------              | 
| Order # | Product   | Qty |              |
-----------------------------              |
|         | Mouse     | 3   |              |
|    1    | Keyboard  | 2   |              | --- List item 1
|         | CPU       | 5   |              |
-----------------------------              |
|         | Mouse     | 1   |              |
|    2    | Keyboard  | 7   |              |
|         | Lan Cable | 7   |              |
-----------------------------              |
                                       ----
                                       ----
2012/11/02                                 |
-----------------------------              |
| Order # | Product   | Qty |              |
-----------------------------              |
|         | Mouse     | 2   |              | --- List item 2
|         | Keyboard  | 8   |              |
|    3    | Memory    | 4   |              |
|         | CPU       | 2   |              |
|         | Battery   | 1   |              |
-----------------------------              |
                                       ----
```

Alternatively you can make one big table:

- group rows on the date
- below that, group rows on the order id
- create a group header for the topmost group, merge the cells in the header, and display the date there

In this approach I'm not 100% sure if you can easily repeat the headers with each item in the date-group.